# Generics error, variable name does not exist on type T

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typing

i have a problem with typescript generics. here is the code :

interface :

```
export interface Hero {
  id: number
  name: string
  localized_name: string
  avatar: string
}

export interface Item {
  id: number
  name: string
  cost: number
  secret_shop: boolean
  side_shop: boolean
  recipe: boolean
  localized_name: string
  avatar: string
}
```

the function itself

```
export const getContent = async <T>(genre: string): Promise<T[]> => {
  const res = await fetch(`${apiEndpoint}${genre})
  const response = await res.json()
  const defaultContent = response.result[category]
  const contentWithImage = defaultContent.map((item: T) => {
    const contentImageUrl = `${imgURL}${item.name.replace('__', '')}.png`

    return { ...item,  avatar: contentImageUrl }
  })
  return contentWithImage
}
```

called this way :

```
const heroes = await getContent<Hero>('heroes')
```

or

```
const items = await getContent<Hero>('items')
```

i get a name is undefined on type  (on item within map) and i really don't get it

if you have any hints,
thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to access properties of `T` you will need to add a constraint. A constraint ensures that any argument passed in meets the constraint requirements.

```
export const getContent = async <T extends { name : string }>(genre: string): Promise<T[]> => {
  const res = await fetch(`${apiEndpoint}${genre}`)
  const response = await res.json()
  const defaultContent = response.result[category]
  const contentWithImage = defaultContent.map((item: T) => {
    const contentImageUrl = `${imgURL}${item.name.replace('__', '')}.png`

    return { ...item,  avatar: contentImageUrl }
  })
  return contentWithImage
}
```

Having generic type parameters that must be specified explicitly is usually not recommended. If you just have these two options, overloads might be a better choice:

```
async function getContent (genre: "heroes"): Promise<Hero[]>
async function getContent (genre: "items"): Promise<Item[]> 
async function getContent (genre: string): Promise<(Item | Hero)[]>{
  const res = await fetch(`${apiEndpoint}${genre}`)
  const response = await res.json()
  const defaultContent = response.result[category]
  const contentWithImage = defaultContent.map((item: Item | Hero) => {
    const contentImageUrl = `${imgURL}${item.name.replace('__', '')}.png`

    return { ...item,  avatar: contentImageUrl }
  })
  return contentWithImage
}
```

Comment: Hmmm i see, isn't there a way to make sure that my variable `item` is either of type `Hero` or `Item` depending on `<T>` ? because to me tha'ts what `item: T` means but i must be wrong

Comment: @Hervé you could go with overloads .. I'll add a version

Comment: @Hervé added the version

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The pattern is not good at all but it was a question purely about generics. I would split with into two methods if this code had to go to production ;)

Comment: You could make the constraint `T extends (Hero | Item)` or extract a common `INamed` interface from both and use that in the constraint.